# How to hide a discard button in openerp 7?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I need to hide the discard button from a page in openerp. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: But why would you want that?

Comment: I add new menu to create PO for different types of product. When I click the discard button it is stays nonfunctional. So I just want to remove it from that form only.

Comment: Try having the menu action to open it as a "popup". Check the Action's `target` attribute .

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit the form buttons template and hide the button from the form.

```
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
   <t t-extend="FormView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="div[class=oe_form_button_cancel]" t-operation="replace">
            <a href="#" class="oe_bold oe_form_invisible oe_form_button_cancel" accesskey="D">Discard</a>
        </t>
   </t>
</templates>
```

Hope this help

Regards,

Comment: I am already inhering purchase order. Can you please give me a example how?

Comment: @user1576199, it will remove discard button from every form.is it possible to remove the discard button only from 1 specific view?

Comment: @OmaL, it is possible but you have to do changes in server side as well in web side, both side

Answer (score 0):

This would seem pointless as you can't stop them using the back button on the browser (or just closing the browser).

Apologies if this seems silly but do you mean you want to stop them deleting the object?